# Allow a contact to select Employer using a profile form in Drupal account registration or Standalone

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, profile, forms

I would like to know how to create a profile that allows a user/contact to select their employer (Organization) while at the same time allow them to fill out standard contact/individual information like First Name and Last Name.

Currently I get an error message that says "Cannot add or update profile field type Organization with combination of Household or Member or Activity" whenever trying to create a profile to do the above.

How can a profile be created to allow for a user to add their contact details AND their employer details

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Hello @trevorforrest!  You mention profiles, but also tagged this as "webform-civicrm".  Those are two different tools.  Which one are you using?  The answer is different for both.  Also - you say you want people to select their employer, but then you say you want people to enter employer details.  Do you need people to just enter their employer's name, or more information about the employer?  Webform-CiviCRM does both.  Profiles does the first but not the second.

Comment: Thanks for the response....so to be specific i use profile in the contect of CiviCRM profile which can be found under Administer > Custom Data  Screens > Profiles in CiviCRM...apologies for the confusion.
As it relates to selecting employer I would like to create a profile that can then be used to allow users to be able to select their employer (where the employer is an Organization that exists in the CiviCRM database). Hope this clarifies.

Webform CiviCRM only seems to facilitate the employer choice when the user is logged in. I am trying to have it do so when they are not logged in.

Comment: Please edit your question to make clear that you're looking to select an organization in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you're looking for the [public autocomplete of organisation names](https://civicrm.org/extensions/public-autocomplete-of-organisation-names) extension.  Then you must include the "Current Employer" field on the profile.

Note that when using traditional CiviCRM profiles, you can't collect information about the organization itself.  You can only allow the individual to specify the employer name.  If you need to collect information about the organization, you will need to use either Webform-CiviCRM or FormBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for this....I did nto know if this extension. Ok so I installed it...did the suggested addition to the civicrm_settings.php file added the "Current Employer" field to the profile  and updated the AJAX permissions in drupal...however the autocomplete does not seem to work.
Are there any gotchas I may need to know about?

Comment: None I can think of - but maybe check the "Network" tab in your browser's Developer Tools (press "F12" to open) as you do a full reload of the page?  Look for any HTTP requests that come back with something other than 200 and view the response.